# Passing sql query as a parameter in http request

Tags: sql, http

I tried to send sql query in http GET request. It's working fine but is there any problem when doing like this ?

Is it advisable ?

Comment: Before you'll get answers like "it's fine as long as you prevent the words 'DELETE' and 'UPDATE' in the query": no, it's not fine. And Stack Overflow is not your security review board. You may want to look into existing solutions, like OData.

Answer (score 0):

No.
It would open up all kinds of security issues, such as [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: SQL injections are present with or without using GET... adding a hash would secure the contents of the GET data and prevent this causing a problem